# How to create multiple pages per post?

Tags: jekyll

For my site some of the posts represent events. For these events I want two representations: the normal html version and an ics version.

How can I use jekyll to make a second version of the same post with a different layout?

I tried to specify multiple layouts in the front matter, but that does not seem to work

```
layout: post, ics
```

or

```
layout: [post, ics]
```

how would I do something like this?

Comment: This can be done with a generator plugin http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#generators

Comment: @DavidJacquel That doesn't seem to work with github pages, right?

Comment: You're right, no way to get a custom plugin running on gh-pages. But maybe you can adopt a workflow as seen on http://octopress.org/. Source in a branch and generated pages in an other.

Comment: Bit of a hack, but you could have the "post" stored as JSON or similar, then have the page render using JS as html or ics depending on querystring. You would have to be careful with accessibitliy and SEO ... but a fun project !?

Comment: Sorry to show my ignorance ... what is ICS? Ice cream sandwich? It may be possible to do it all with media queries etc in CSS

Comment: @Ruskin ICS is a calendar format, in the code above the name of a layout I defined in jekyll.

Comment: @Ruskin The CSS approach won't work, because the ICS format is for machines (that won't run any javascript/css or the like)

Comment: There is an interesting conversation on this issue at https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is not currently possible in vanilla Jekyll, but if you can use plugins, the [multipost](https://github.com/saclark/jekyll-multipost) plugin found on this jekyll [issue](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3041) should do what you want.